# In Lisp, meaning of different levels

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As part of a homework, the professor said that each expressions can have a maximum of 3 levels.

Just to make sure I understand it:

Does the following have 2 levels?
`( (a) (b) )`

And does the following have 3 levels?

`( a ( b (c) ) )`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard Lisp terminology, so it depends on what the professor means. In particular, is he just counting list nesting, or does he count the leaf objects as a level as well.

What "level" would he consider an atom all by itself (not in a list)? Whatever that is, your first example is 2 more levels, and the second is 3 more.